# How to use range slider updated values (on change) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, javascript-objects

Let say i have created a slider and i am changing the value of slider using mouse. How can i use these values as variable in global scope, this variable should change to updated value when i changed the slider. I want to use the slider value in canvas to update my object.

```
HTML
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1" onchange="myFn()" >

JS
function myFn(){
  let a = document.getElementbyId("slider").value;
  console.log(a); //value change here how value is use outside the function.
}
```

Comment: can you please provide any stackblitz or codesandbox url?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is being misspelled: document.getElementById, letter b needs to be capitalized

Please try again with HTML:

```
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1">
```

and javascript

```
let slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    
slider.onchange = function(){
  console.log(this.value)
}
```

Comment: It is typo. But the code is not working.